# Enabling mod_deflate don't compress HTTP responses

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I decided to upgrade from Apache 2.4.10 to Apache 2.4.20 (I need it to use HTTP/2), downloaded it and installed it from sources (whereas I installed Apache 2.4.10 from debian repositories) with `mod_deflate` enabled with the following commands:

```
./configure --enable-deflate --enable-http2 --with-nghttp2=/usr/local/lib
make
make install
```

I then added the following lines to my conf file (`/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`):

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

But when I request an html page with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, Apache's answer is not compressed, why?

It worked with 2.4.10 installed from repositories, however, the configuration file I had to change was `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf` so I wonder if I am not missing something when compiling 2.4.20 from sources.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to enable both **filter** and **deflate** modules.

```
sudo a2enmod deflate
sudo a2enmod filter
```